# Как программно добавлять текст на конкретные строчки label?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Создала label через `main.storyboard`, поставила lines = 2, мне стало интересно, как **программно** добавлять текст в этот label на определенные строчки?

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой способ начать текст со второй строки - спереди добавить в текст перенос строки `\n`

```
label.text = "\nВаш текст"
```